# Question about using nuxtjs (frontend) with laravel (backend)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js

**My question**:


Some people use 2 separate servers.
One for frontend, One for backend and uses API to make communication.


I don't know how to run 2 separate parts (frontend and backend) on a single remove server? how should i upload both nuxtjs (frontend) and laravel applications (API backend) on a single server on internet and make them work together.

**For example:**

mydomain.com --> frontend (Nuxt)

mydomain.com/api --> backend (Laravel)


**My directory structure:**
[image]
**client folder**: nuxt application (npx create-nuxt-app client)

**Server folder**: laravel application (composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel server)

Comment: I think the easiest would be to use a subdomain for the api, e.g. api.mydomain.com which redirects to the server folder, and your normal mydomain.com redirects to the client folder

Comment: this highly depends on your server. Can you give us a bit more information? Are you on a simple shared host - or do you have ssh access and can install and manage node, apache or nginx yourself? 
For my virtual Servers I use a "reverse proxy" to proxy all requests that go towards /api to my backend while all other request go for the frontend.

Comment: @FrankProvost I'm on simple shared host

Comment: This might be tricky then - does  you hoster support node.js? Otherwise you will not be able to run a node.js based server for nuxt

Comment: Probably using 2 separate servers would probably be a good choice for me in this case.Thank for ur reply, 
I really appreciate it.